# Protoc-gen-gogo compiler issue with go

Tags: go, protobuf-go

```
Step 1:- add following dependencies
```

> github.com/gogo/protobuf/proto [ok]
> github.com/gogo/protobuf/protoc-gen-gogo[ok]
> github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto[ok]
> google.golang.org/grpc[ok]

```
Step 2:- 
  create proto file in a project 
Step 3:-
  change directory and type this command
```

> protoc --gogo_out=. greet

```
error:=
protoc-gen-gogo: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using the absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable.
--gogo_out: protoc-gen-gogo: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

PLease help me

Comment: It seems you did not install protoc-gen-gogo on your system. Install it using go get github.com/gogo/protobuf/protoc-gen-gogo and try again. For more help refer to this - https://github.com/gogo/protobuf

Answer (score 1):

It seems you did not install `protoc-gen-gogo` on your system.
Install it using `go get github.com/gogo/protobuf/protoc-gen-gogo` and try again.
For more help refer to this - https://github.com/gogo/protobuf

Comment: First I will check if I will add go get github.com/gogo/protobuf/protoc-gen-gofast in my system. protoc --gofast_out=. *.proto ERROR: --gofast_out: protoc-gen-gofast: Plugin failed with status code 1. NOW TRY SOMETHING ELSE :(

Comment: all the dependencies include which are mention in repo include in my system protoc --gofast_out=. *.proto                                                                                                           ERROR : protoc-gen-gofast: program not found or is not executable

Comment: Check if GOBIN is properly set in the path

Comment: Problem solved https://github.com/ali2210/peers-peers